# LNK1104: Cannot Open File "\include.obj" - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, linker

I'm very new to OPEN CV. I've used the 3.2.0 Version and visual studio 15.

I've followed the same installation procedures recommended online.

So I'm trying to run the image threshold tutorial (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)
and when I build it I get the above error.

I'm a bit lost in debugging this and can't find the similar error for this. I have added the pictures for my setup here to check if there were errors in the setup.
[Current Linker setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBTOd.png)

Comment: Can you add values assigned for `Additional include directories` and `Additional library directories` in the project settings to the question? That is better to copy all values as strings than making pictures (screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that project settings are not set properly.

First, check include directories in section

> Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additionals Include Directories

Than, for linking

> Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additionals Library Directories

Refer to OpenCV documentation for details and to similar questions ([like this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/22734/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-obj/) or [this](http://linkopencvtovs.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-link-opencv-to-microsoft-visual.html)) for more detailed answers and values of settings.

**UPDATE:**

I have looked at picture referenced in the question. And found value `$(OPENCV_ROOT)\include` in section `Additional dependencies`, while this value is likely for section `Additionals Include Directories`... dependencies are for `lib` files, like `...\lib\opencv_world320d.lib`.

So check once again value of `Additionals Include Directories` in `General` sections for `C/C++` and also make sure that environment variable `OPENCV_ROOT` has right value (together with `\include` makes folder where sub-folders `opencv` and `opencv2` are located.

Comment: @user3504972 Look at pictures at page http://linkopencvtovs.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-link-opencv-to-microsoft-visual.html - that provide examples how values for Include, Library and Dependencies look like (values depend on OpenCV and Visual Studio versions, but `\include` should not be in `Dependencies`)